# Помощь в кодировании URL.

Tags: url, php, http

**Здравствуйте!**

Вот я пытаюсь закодировать URL, содержащий GET-запрос. Схема примерно такая:

```
http://site.com/profile?_spirix__.-^[]#*%!~@+
```

Как вы, конечно же, поняли, GET-запрос, это

```
_spirix__.-^[]#*%!~@+
```

Так вот пытаюсь закодировать данную строку для того, чтобы по ссылке можно было перейти, и сервер обработал этот запрос. Пробовал юзать **urlencode()**, результат:

```
http://site.com/profile?_spirix__.-%5E%5B%5D%23%2A%25%21~%40%2B
```

Вроде бы все нормально, как кажется на первый взгляд...но вывожу данные запроса( а именно то, что идет после знака вопроса, т.е **"_spirix__.-%5E%5B%5D%23%2A%25%21~%40%2B"**), и вот что мне выдается:

```
 _spirix___-^
```

Почему? Куда делись остальные кодированные символы**( []#*%!~@+ )** ??? Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, ребят?

**Большое спасибо тем, кто поможет!**

Comment: Ребят, все дело оказалось в том, что я передавал данные GET-запросом Через ключи суперглобального массива $_GET:

    http://site.loc/profile?_spirix__.-%5E%5D%5B%23%2A%25%21~%40%2B

А надо было через значения:

    http://site.loc/profile?id=_spirix__.-%5E%5D%5B%23%2A%25%21~%40%2B

---
Но ответ участника @just495 меня больше всего обрадовал из всех остальных. Я даже не задумывался о данном преобразовании. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего, дело в [].

Образуется массив

```
Array ( [_spirix___-^] => Array ( [0] => ) ) 1
```

а без `[` нормально

```
Array ( [_spirix___-^]#*%!~@+] => ) 1
```

Comment: Да, вы правы! Дело и правда оказалось в скобках! Даже не в скобках, а в одной "[". Буду думать, как исправлять. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте    `rawurlencode ( string $str )`

[rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: Пробовал. Не получается.

---
Да, и к тому же, разницы кодирования между данными функциями почти нет. Только разные стандарты используют...

Comment: вы раскодируете его rawurldecode???

Comment: @ROOT, и так тоже пробовал - не помогает(((

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = urlencode('_spirix__.-^[]#*%!~@+');
var_dump(urldecode($test)); //string(21) "_spirix__.-^[]#*%!~@+"
```

работает нормально, выводится оригинальная строка, 
вероятно проблема в другом месте

Comment: Тут дело в GET-запросе...так-то у меня тоже все работает...